# NodeJs gives error that backticks are ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-error

I am trying to run a NodeJs application; however, when I run it, any use of back-ticks will give the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I am using them for string interpolation and I prefer not to change them all to double quotes. Thank you.

Comment: Can you give us a code example of how you are using them?  I know they work, as I'm using them in my own Express application.

Comment: What version of node

Comment: I am using version v0.12.2.

Comment: @DaveV Here is an example line `reject(\`Error [radioChannelSet]: ${data}\`);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Node version 4 or above.

http://node.green/#template-literals

Comment: Not sure what this was down voted...seems pretty clear to me

Comment: Thanks @DaveV! I wasn't sure either.